# How can I prevent a Zabbix server from listening on port 10051

Tags: linux, zabbix

The Zabbix server by default listens on TCP port 10051 for data sent by trapper items. In my configuration I don't use any trapper items, so I would like to prevent the Zabbix server from listening on port 10051, or any other port for that matter.

I tried setting

```
ListenPort=
```

in the Zabbix server configuration, but this resulted in the server not starting up anymore. I also tried

```
ListenPort=0
```

but with the same result.

So how can I prevent Zabbix from listening on a TCP port for trapper items?

System info:

- Debian jessie
- With Zabbix 3.0.3+dfsg-1 from jessie-backports

Comment: @techraf It is already commented out by default. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This configuration option does the trick:

```
StartTrappers=0
```

Beware: I found this note in the documentation:

> At least one trapper process must be running to display server availability and view queue in the frontend.

I don't know yet what this means, but so far I haven't found any detrimental effects in the web frontend yet.

If it turns out that the web frontend really requires listening for trapper items then the following configuration option could be set so that the server at least does not listen on the public network interface:

```
ListenIP=127.0.0.1
```

I haven't tested this yet, though.

Comment: Administration -> Queue won't work; global scripts (like ping, traceroute etc) won't work; server status in the dashboard and Zabbix status report won't work.

Comment: I was just going to mention the `ListenIP` and `ListenPort`  in `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf` in case other people were looking for the file/option